# Compile .img on OSX

Tags: image, bare-metal

How do I create a .img file on a mac?  I am trying to create a basic OS but after writing some basic C (roughly following [this](http://wiki.osdev.org/Raspberry_Pi_Bare_Bones) tutorial) what do I do to put that code on the Pi?

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/Raspberry_Pi_Bare_Bones#Testing_your_operating_system_.28Real_Hardware.29

Comment: that didn't produce a .img file for me...  :(

Comment: sorry, it did produce a image for me but i am unsure of what to do now...

Answer (score 1):

Open the Disk Utility app and create a New Image.  This will give you options such as format (Mac Extended, MS-DOS, etc).  Once you create it, a disc image will be created and opened where ever you tell it to save it.  You can then put whatever files you want in to it.  Once you've put the files in, eject the open image.  The disc image will be saved as a ".dmg" file, but you can simply change it to a ".img" file.